# angularjs get payload from request from another app

Tags: angularjs

Here I have two apps trying to communicate with each other.

appA sending a URL to browser, the URL will consists some params and a form body.
appB will receive the URL on frontend angularjs, and extract the payload before sending another request to the backend server to authenticate.

currently, I can only extract the parameters from URL string.
What if there is a form body from appA URL, how can appB read the form body?

[image]

NOTE:

- I tried to search and all I got is an HTTP POST request sent out. my question is about reading the payload on the receiving end.
- the reason for the above design is due to security concerns. We read from frontend and only pass certain values to backend, instead of directly to the backend as is.